# Toast does not show Jelly Bean

Tags: android, toast, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I am having an activity and I have to show Toast message to the user. OS version is Jelly Bean, show notifications is turned on. This works on Ice Cream Sandwitch. Here is the code:

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Could somebody knows what is the problem?

Comment: Depends on what "this" is - I had some problems displaying toasts using context of activity that wasn't visible at that time (say, being in the onStop phase). Maybe try replacing it with getApplicationContext()

Comment: I first try it with getApplicationContext() .It does not work also.

Comment: I am calling this in the method onActivityResult , you think that this can be a problem?

Comment: That should be fine. I would rather ask whether the code runs at all. Maybe you could add some Log.d(...) messages after/before it, just to make sure. (Yeah, I read that it runs on ICS, but, weird things happen - this way you can at least verify it's a problem with the toast itself and not something else)

Comment: You are right. On Jelly Bean this does not run at all

Answer (score 1):

Try using this code:

```
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```